# Disable sharepoint on client system

Tags: sharepoint-online

My client is continually getting a Sharepoint login dialogue and he doesn't know why. He was recently asked to share a file through Sharepoint, but as that was a one-day event he has no further use of the platform. Nevertheless, he is constantly bombarded with this login dialogue for something he doesn't need and doesn't want. Further, there are no uninstall listings in either the App Management or in Programs and Features. I'm hoping there is a command-line option or registry setting, or even that it is registered under a different name in the usual interfaces as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method or need to disable SharePoint Online since it is a cloud-based product. The client is getting login dialogue possibly because he has used his account in Office clients or web browser (IE, Edge, Chrome, etc.).

Try asking the client to add the SharePoint Online site to the **trusted sites** or local intranet list via *Internet Options* to disable the login dialogue.

--

On the other hand, you can remove this user’s access from your tenant by [removing the guest account](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-properly-deactivate-a-user-in-office-365-and-sharepoint/) (if any) and deleting the sharing link as well.

And for the client, I suggest checking all Office clients (e.g., Word, OneDrive) and browser during this sharing process, remove the service linked to SPO and clear the cache of the clients and browser.